# Get data value from specific column of string

Tags: php

I need to take out some info from a string. What I need to get is the data from the second value from the second line for example, anyway depending of the user I can need the data from the third line or another one. Is it possible to make a query to get this info?

Regards

```
$searchLine = "13";

$str  = "[
      [1, u'G4622', u'2300866', u'1111', u'zzzz'],
      [2, u'G4622', u'2300873', u'2222', u'zzzz'],
      [13, u'G4626', u'2300975', u'3333', u'zzzz'],
    ]";
$str = str_replace('u', '', $str);
$str = array($str);
print_r($str);

 /*
Array
(
   [0] => [
      [1, 'G4622', '2300866', '1111', 'zzzz'],
      [2, 'G4622', '2300873', '2222', 'zzzz'],
      [13, 'G4626', '2300975', '3333', 'zzzz'],
    ]
 )


 //want to get 2300975
```

Comment: you mean some function that you can pass the line and the position of the value in the line and you get the result ? should be fairly easy.

Comment: Hi, yes, I want to get the value of the second column but it dependes of the first number of the line.  So,  it would be like finding the ID of the line and then get the value of the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches for your task:

1. If the string description has a fixed format, then you can select the desired part by cutting the string into delimiters and getting a substring with the desired number (as done in the get_value_dummy function);
2. A more flexible way is to try to parse the string using the eval function and work with the result as a full-fledged array (the get_value_smart function).

Below is an example of both approaches:

```
<?php

function get_value_dummy($str, $row_id, $column_num)
{
    $arr = explode("[".$row_id.",", $str, 2);
    if(count($arr) < 2)
        return null;
    $arr = explode("]", $arr[1], 2);
    if(count($arr) < 2)
        return null;
    $arr = explode(",", $arr[0]);
    if($column_num >= count($arr))
        return null;
    return trim($arr[$column_num-1], " '");
}

function get_value_smart($str, $row_id, $column_num)
{
    eval("\$arr=".$str.";");
    if(is_null($arr) || (is_array($arr) == false))
        return null;
    foreach($arr as $subarr)
    {
        if(!is_array($subarr) || empty($subarr))
            continue;
        if(reset($subarr) == $row_id)
            return array_key_exists($column_num, $subarr)?$subarr[$column_num]:null;
    }
    return null;
}

$searchLine = "13";

$str  = "[
      [1, u'G4622', u'2300866', u'1111', u'zzzz'],
      [2, u'G4622', u'2300873', u'2222', u'zzzz'],
      [13, u'G4626', u'2300975', u'3333', u'zzzz'],
    ]";
$str = str_replace('u', '', $str);

assert(get_value_dummy($str, $searchLine, 2) == "2300975");
assert(get_value_smart($str, $searchLine, 2) == "2300975");

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but what about if I just want to get the value instead of 2300975, just the ramdom value in the column? The "searchline" variable could be any other number, so the column value would be different.

Comment: You can pass any string value as the row number to both functions as $row_id parameters, and any column number to $column_num.
If the specified row or column does not exist, then null will be returned.

Comment: For example, all of these statements will also work:
 
assert(get_value_dummy($str, "1", 4) == "zzzz");
assert(get_value_dummy($str, "2", 3) == "2222");
assert(get_value_smart($str, "x", 3) == null);
assert(get_value_smart($str, "1", 5) == null);
assert(get_value_smart($str, "2", 0) == "2"); // column zero contains the row number itself
assert(get_value_dummy($str, "2", 0) == null); // for get_value_dummy function null column does not exist

Comment: Another small addition: in the get_value_dummy function, the line "if($column_num >= count($arr))" should be added as "if(($column_num <= 0)||($column_num > count($arr)))", so that it correctly returns the value for the null and the last column.